# I want to run a independent t-test to determine if the difference between the mean reaction time for 2 groups is significant?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have 2 groups doing the same test and recorded their reaction times, however the sample size/observations for the groups are not equal. One is 54 and the other only 14. How would I go about doing a power calculations and interpret the p-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having unequal group sizes is not much of a problem, but it does reduce the power of a t-test relative to what you would have if the overall sample size was evenly distributed between the groups and it makes the t-test a little more strongly affected by deviations from the assumption of equal variances.

Once you have the data in hand there is no good reason to perform a power test unless you are planning to gather a new set of data. The power of the test and the p-value that you obtain have a one-to-one relationship (because they are both calculated using the same statistics and parameter values).

You can (often, should) use the mean and variance estimates from your current data in a power analysis to determine the desirable sample size for a new study.